# Ubuntu VirtualHost on port 8003 not working remotly

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I trying create Apache Virtual Host on port 8003.

My site configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.oracle.dev.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:8003>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

    ServerName test.oracle.tf
    
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2

    ServerName test.oracle.tf

    <Directory "/var/www/html/test2">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ports.conf:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:8003

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

UFW is disable for test.

I try connect from other host (Windows OS) .
I added `test.oracle.tf` to host file.

Site: `test.oracle.tf` is working corectly.

But site: `test.oracle.tf:8003` does't work.

When I trying open site  `test.oracle.tf:8003` `tcpdump port 8003` showing:
[image: TCP DUMP]

`curl 127.0.0.1:8003`
corectly showing page content

What I Was made wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tcpdump` output shows that you don't get any responses to your requests. As you said that port 80 works normally then IP routing is working. Most probably port 8003 is blocked by a firewall somewhere between source and target hosts.